# Show daily data from current week, Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to fetch data from the current week and not from the last 7 days. My query is:

```
select
        order_datetime_tz::date AS date,
        orders

    FROM
         order_fact f 
        where order_datetime_tz < current_date
        and order_datetime_tz >= date_trunc('week',current_date) - interval '1 week'
```

However this returns me the last 7 days..
Any idea on that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The beginning of the current week is `date_trunc('week',current_date)`, so you just want to query dates later later than that:

```
select
    order_datetime_tz::date AS date,
    orders

FROM
    order_fact f 
    where order_datetime_tz >= date_trunc('week',current_date)
```

Comment: So close! Works perfect! Thanks!